# Add checkbox to right of re-sizable input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn about the DOM and I am having difficulty trying to place a bootstrap checkbox to the right of a re-sizable input field.

First I added my input and the checkbox to a `div`, as I want the checkbox to move depending on the amount of text added to the re-sizable text field. This is what I have so far.

```css
  .answer1Container{
    width: 100%; 
    }
    
    /*Here is the styling for the input field*/
    div.answerInput1 {
        border: 2px solid;
        padding: 20px; 
        margin-top: 4%;
        width: 50%;
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    
    /*Below is styling for the checkboxes of the edit question page*/
    
    .form-group input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .form-group input[type="checkbox"] + .btn-group > label span {
        width: 20px;
    }
    
    .form-group input[type="checkbox"] + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
        display: none;
    }
    .form-group input[type="checkbox"] + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
        display: inline-block;   
    }
    
    .form-group input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .form-group input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
        display: none;   
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="answer1Container"> 
  <div class = "answerInput1">"Here is some content"</div>
    <div class="[ form-group ]">
                <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-primary" class="checkbox" id="fancy-checkbox-primary" autocomplete="off" />
                <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-primary" class="[ btn btn-primary ]">
                        <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                        <span> </span>
                    </label>
                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-primary" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                        This Answer is Correct
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

However, I am not having any luck moving the checkbox. It is staying firmly tucked directly under the input field. I have tried `text-align:right;`, but this has not moved the checkbox. I have also tried to add `padding` etc but no luck (I have removed my failed attempts from my attached CSS for clarity).

In-case my waffle of an explanation isn't clear, I am looking to achieve something like this:

[image]

As a beginner, I would appreciate some guidance on how to achieve this. I would like to keep the design as shown in the code snippet, I just need to understand how to move it as desired. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `float: right;` to the `div.form-group`, and `float: left;` to `div.answerInput1`. That's basically all you need to do move something to the right. The `float: left` is optional and affects whether the checkbox is above or below the textbox. See https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Your code is a bit messy there's definitely a nicer way to do it, but I just wanted to demonstrate how to move the checkbox to the right on your snippet.

```css
.answer1Container{
    width: 100%; 
    }
    
    /*Here is the styling for the input field*/
    div.answerInput1 {
        border: 2px solid;
        padding: 20px; 
        margin-top: 4%;
        width: 50%;
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;
        float: left;
      
    }
    
    /*Below is styling for the checkboxes of the edit question page*/
    div.form-group{
    float:right; 
    
    }
    .form-group input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .form-group input[type="checkbox"] + .btn-group > label span {
        width: 20px;
    }
    
    .form-group input[type="checkbox"] + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
        display: none;
    }
    .form-group input[type="checkbox"] + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
        display: inline-block;   
    }
    
    .form-group input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:first-child {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .form-group input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .btn-group > label span:last-child {
        display: none;   
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="answer1Container"> 
  <div class = "answerInput1">"Here is some content"</div>
    <div class="[ form-group ]">
                <input type="checkbox" name="fancy-checkbox-primary" class="checkbox" id="fancy-checkbox-primary" autocomplete="off" />
                <div class="[ btn-group ]">
                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-primary" class="[ btn btn-primary ]">
                        <span class="[ glyphicon glyphicon-ok ]"></span>
                        <span> </span>
                    </label>
                    <label for="fancy-checkbox-primary" class="[ btn btn-default active ]">
                        This Answer is Correct
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to achive what is in your image:

[image]

```css
#container { font-family: Verdana; position: relative; }
#container > div { font-size: 1.2em; color: darkslategrey; display: flex; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; height: 50px; width: 50px; border: 1px solid silver; box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: lightgrey; }
#container > input[type="text"] { font-size: 1.3em; width: 300px; padding-left: 60px; height: 50px; box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid silver; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>@</div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>Remember me</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this answer doesn't give any explanation and from what I can see, doesn't contain a check-box either...